# Relaxation oscilator with only transistor to measure DC voltage

Tags: voltage, transistors, frequency, converter

I need to measure voltage from 12 to 100 volts with an MCU but with an isolated solution (so no voltage divider), my idea was to use relaxation oscillator coupled to Optocoupler in order to obtain a kind of voltage to frequency converter. I have no way to use OP amp in this schematic since I have no power supply except the MCU one (3,3 volts) and the DC to measure. My main problem is the range of measurement 12 to 100 Volts DC. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I guess you expect some accuracy. A single transistor or UJT oscillator can be insufficient. But there's still numerous other possibilities. How much current is still free to use from your+3.3V? If there's enough more voltages can be generated. What's the wanted accuracy at 12V and at 100V? How fast the DC to be measured changes? For ex. tell the needed sample rate and the averaging window for one sample.

Comment: Asking for "any help" is not good - ask a specific question.

Comment: @user287001 The 3,3 volts will be powered mainly by a Lipo lets say 1000 mA/h , concerning the precision of measurement need to be around 1 % at any range, the measurement will be very slow probably 1 sample per hour, so nothing to deal sample rate.

Comment: @Andyaka I am sorry, my question is probably : Is it possible to use a relaxation circuit to measure DC voltage in certain range with low constraints ?

Comment: Anything is possible and so you need to focus more and ask a properly answerable question. I'm not trying to mess you around - bad questions don't get answered well. Possibly something like "how might I be able to measure a remote galvanically isolated DC voltage using (say) opto couplers or transformers and without having to provide a power source at the isolated side". This may not be exactly what you want to ask but, you do need to ask a question like this.

Comment: @Delphes 1000mA/h isn't a current. You should tell the max allowed peak current and the average, both in milliamperes.

Comment: I will probably put an LDO of 500 mA or 1 Amp maximum.

Comment: For galvanic isolation, I would use an isolated transformer and compare the output. Now the question is what do you want to isolate from what? Can't take a simple voltage comparator circuit adapted for this voltage range and then, transfer the output to the rest of the circuit via an optocoupler?

Comment: @Fredled yes my first idea was optocoupler to isolate the DC part (12-100) to the MCU part, this is why I was thinking a kind of oscilator with 2 NPN transistor , caps and resistor like relaxation oscilator. Trnasformer is fine, but not easy to find.

Comment: Not easy to find? https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20200518132837&SearchText=Isolation+Transformer+miniature

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot have a galvanic contact between your 12...100V DC and the rest of your system. The "rest of your system" has only 3,3VDC operating voltage which is used to supply a microcomputer and you try to avoid generating higher voltages from it. I guess the microcomputer has analog input for voltage measurements and it has a way to send the measurement result to some external system that you are not going to present here.

You wrote in a comment one measurement per hour is enough. In that case you can sample the 12...100V DC with a flying capacitor (=both ends moved with a relay) which has a series resistor to keep the current acceptable during the sampling for long relay life. After taking the sample the flying cap is discharged to a pre-discharged bigger capacitor to lower the voltage say to 1...2%. The result is converted to digital.

Capacitors are not precision components but I guess you can choose stable types and calibrate the conversion in software.

12 bit conversion should be enough for the wanted accuracy.

You didn't specify the needed isolation. Miniature relays which can operate at 3V coil voltage do not have especially long gap between the contacts, so it's well possible that relays with long enough isolation gap do not exist.

Comment: Thanks in my original question (certainly bad fomuled) I wrote optocoupler, since it was my idea to isolate the 12-100 VDC part to teh rest of the circuit which is MCU.